# Is it possible to combine array like this:

Tags: php

I have two Arrays

```
Array
(
   [0] => Sally
   [1] => Apple
)

Array
(
   [0] => McSalad
   [1] => Tuna
)
```

Is it possible to combine these two like this?

```
Array
    (
       [0] => Sally McSalad
       [1] => Apple Tuna
    )
```

How?..

Comment: sure, did you read first the official guide? php.net/foreach, php.net/arrays

Comment: Yes, anything's possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
$res = [];

foreach($array1 as $key =>$val) {
   $res[$key] = $val . ' ' . $array2[$key];
}

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if there is difference in the size of both arrays, this will still work.

**with foreach**

```
$i=0;
foreach($arrayFirst as $value){
   $newValue= $value;
   if(key_exists($i,$secondArray){
      $newValue.=' '.$secondArray[$i++]; 
   }
 $newArray[]=$newValue;
}
```

**with for**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($firstArray);$i++){

   $newValue= $firstArray[$i];
   if(key_exists($i,$secondArray){
      $newValue.=' '.$secondArray[$i]; 
   }
 $newArray[]=$newValue;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

*One-line* solution using `array_map` function:

```
$result = array_map(function($v){ return $v[0].' '.$v[1]; }, array_map(null, $arr1, $arr2));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sally McSalad
    [1] => Apple Tuna
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

$a und $b are arrays of same length

$c is the new array containing the concatenated strings

```
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++) {
    $c[$i] = $a[$i] . " " . $b[$i];
}
```